# How do I authenticate a User on my API against Steam?

Tags: java, reactjs, api, openid, steam

I have a React Web App and an API Endpoint. Now I want to authenticate (≠ authorize) a user based on their Steam account, probably with OpenID I assume.

Here is a small dialogue + [drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTYDx.png) to sum up my idea:

**MRWA**: Hey, I'm Joe, let me authenticate on your side with my Steam username and password. (Green Arrow)
**Steam**: Ah I see, you are Joe - calling redirect URL now. (Yellow Arrow)
**MRWA**: I got the authentication-token + SteamID and will send it to MA. (Red Arrow)
**MA**: Got your authentication-token + SteamID. I'll check if your token is valid because you could send me any SteamID right?... Hey Steam, is this token valid and could you return the SteamID if so? (Orange Arrows)
**Steam**: Token is valid, here is your SteamID connected to the token you sent me.
**MA**: Gotcha, I'll now send MRWA an access token for myself so I don't have to ask you again.

How do I archive this?

Comment: There is no OAuth on this site. And their OAuth docs (https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi_overview/oauth) don't show how to validate a token. Also they don't specify what a client_id is and how to get it.

Comment: Oh, he removed his comment.

Comment: Related question: [Secure Login on Steam](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/137153/5379).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the methods outlined on Steamworks [User Authentication and Ownership](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/features/auth):

> Between a game client and other clients (P2P) or game servers using [Session Tickets](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/features/auth#client_to_client)
>
> - Between a game client and a backend server using:
>
>   - [Session Tickets and the Steamworks Web API](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/features/auth#client_to_backend_webapi)
>   - [Encrypted Application Ticket Library](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/features/auth#encryptedapptickets)
> - When a user is in a web browser using [OpenID and Steamworks Web API](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/features/auth#website)

That documentation is more likely to have an accurate answer for your use case, but I'll describe one option.

If your React Web App is a game/app on Steam, then can use the steam API to generate a ticket completely automatically so the user doesn't need to do any additional login. You can probably find a JavaScript wrapper for that API, but which one is likely dependent on the server is running your app (i.e., nodejs).

You can use the Steamworks Web API to authenticate the user in your backend: In the web app, you call [ISteamUser.GetAuthTicketForWebApi](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/api/ISteamUser#GetAuthTicketForWebApi) through the native API and send that ticket to the server and on the server you use the [ISteamUserAuth/AuthenticateUserTicket](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi/ISteamUserAuth#AuthenticateUserTicket) webapi endpoint. No steam-specific libraries required on the server.

As the docs note mentions, the webapi call requires a [publisher API key](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi_overview/auth#publisher-keys), which you [create with your admin Steamworks account](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi_overview/auth#create_publisher_key). Never include your API key with an executable downloaded by users or they can wreak havoc!

If your React Web App is not a game/app on Steam, then you likely need to use OpenID instead. You'll have to show a login page to the user.

Answer (score -2):

Use this Library. https://github.com/SmItH197/SteamAuthentication

This will work for everything you need.

If you go into it, you'll see it has a way for you to authenticate users, and check to see if they are signed in with `if(!isset($_SESSION['steamid']))`

Then you can perform any task you may need to, and authenticate if it still is the correct user.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is PHP but my React Web App isn't based on PHP at all.